# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: quiz_gradingmodel

Tags: django

This occurred after running `python manage.py makemigrations` after a new model known as "gradingmodel" was added into models.py

What I did before running `makemigrations`

1. all db.sqlite3 was deleted.
2. all migrations file was deleted.
3. all relevant pycache file was deleted.

PS: after commenting out the newly added model, `makemigrations` seems to work, I'm not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

```
python manage.py makemigrations quiz  

Loading list of models into cache

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

  File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlit
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: quiz_gradingmodel
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()

File "manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_
utility.execute()

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_
django.setup()

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", lin
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py"
app_config.ready()

File "C:\wamp64\www\GitHub\GitHub\cosmos\quiz\apps.py", line 16, in ready
for model in model_to_deploy:

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.p
results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_siz

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\com
cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils
\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\liuyo\.virtualenvs\GitHub-s0ZEke5K\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlit
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: quiz_gradingmodel
```

Comment: Try this "manage.py migrate --run-syncdb"

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the same issue still occurs,  "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: quiz_gradingmodel".
Nevertheless, thank you for the Suggestion :)

Comment: Delete all migration directory and files from root and apps. Delete all pycache files and directory from root and apps, delete sqlite file then make migrations for each apps and migrate

Comment: Hi Praveen, thank you for the reply, I've found the problem, there was a function above my models.py that was calling the class before if was even defined. Thx for the help though :D